# Packages are recognised by normal script but not by service?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, package-management, services

my bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
. ~/er/erl/activate
kiex use 1.13.4
mix phx.server
```

i user kerl and kiex to manage my erlang and elixir installations

I am trying to use this script in my service;

```
 [Unit]
Description=BlockScout Server
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=ubuntu
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/blockscout
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/startBlockscout.sh
EnvironmentFile=/usr/local/blockscout/env_vars.env

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

as you can see, startBlockscout.sh is the name of my bash script. i intend to run this script as a part of the Execstart field in a linux service

i want to know, how can i make sure that my script recognises the kerl and kiez while running in a service

i keep getting the errors;

```
line 3: kiex: command not found
line 4: mix: command not found
```

if i try to use the same commands in a bash script that i launch directly from the shell, the commands of kiex and mix work !

they just don't work when i am trying to execute them using the service

any advice is greatly appreciated !

Comment: What user is the script running as (i.e., what directory is `~` in the script referring to when running as a service)?

Comment: Are you using the full paths of the commands in the script? I assume that the `PATH` variable of the ubuntu-user does load the commands only via e.g. bashrc, which would not happen for the service.

Comment: @FelixJN how can i make it happen for the service ?

Comment: @Kusalananda the username is Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kiex` and `mix` are probably installed into a path that is added to your search path (the `PATH` environment variable) when you log in or start an interactive shell.

Since the service neither logs you in nor starts an interactive shell, that doesn't happen.

So, simply specify the full path to `kiex` and `mix`.

Comment: kiex is the version manager for elixir. do you think specifying kiex should help me use mix ?

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear about the instructions – specify the full path path of `kiex` and `mix`, instead of just saying `kiex` and `mix`.

Comment: entschuldigung , i was just asking to confirm